# How to escape the | when running sed via SSH

Tags: sed

I am running the sed command to add a string to a line in a file:
This is the original line:

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Doption=Xyz"
```

It will be updated to:

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=false -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=.abc.com|.abc1.com|localhost -Dhttps.proxyPort=443 -Doption=Xyz"
```

This is the command:

```
sed -i '1 s/export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="/export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=false -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=.abc.com|.abc1.com|localhost -Dhttps.proxyPort=443 /1 ' startup.sh
```

This works fine when it is run on the command line on the server. However it fails to run when it is done via SSH:

```
ssh @hostname 'sed -i '1 s/export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="/export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=false -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=.abc.com|.abc1.com|localhost -Dhttps.proxyPort=443 /1 ' startup.sh'
```

I believe it has something to do with the "|". I even tried using 3 backlashes:

```
ssh @hostname 'sed -i '1 s/export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="/export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=false -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=.abc.com\\\|.abc1.com\\\|localhost -Dhttps.proxyPort=443 /1 ' startup.sh'
```

I replaced the | with 3 backlashes:

```
ssh @hostname 'sed -i '1 s/export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="/export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=false -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=.abc.com\\\.abc1.com\\\localhost -Dhttps.proxyPort=443 /1 ' startup.sh'
```

Still it is failing.
Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Suggestion: Reduce your command size, it is a pain to scroll horizontally to see each of your codes. This is called creating a minimal (but complete!) example. You do not need the *whole* "-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=false -Dhttp.proxySet=false -Dhttp.proxyHost=host1 ..." string to prove your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ssh @hostname "$(cat <<'EOT'

sed -i ... # your command, verbatim

EOT
)"
```

Comment: Why `cat` ? You can just do `ssh @hostname sh <<'EOT' `

Comment: @annahri That's different -- it will pass the script via its stdin, which will cause bash to do a system call for each byte, and will have other unintended effects.

Comment: Thank you @un
I did ran that, but getting an e

Comment: Thanks @UncleBilly
It worked without any errors. Just curious - any reason why direct sed -i didnt work ?
I am still learning ...

Comment: Single quotes do not nest. With `ssh @hostname 'sed -i '1 ... ' startup.sh'`, the arguments passed to ssh will be `sed -i '1` ... many separate arguments ... `startup.sh`, not `sed`, `-i`, `1 s/.../` and `startup.sh`. After connecting to the remote server, ssh will join all those arguments with spaces, and pass them as a single argument (via `-c`) to the login shell of the remote user. The remote login shell will interpret that again as a script (expanding variables, interpreting pipes, etc).

Comment: Basically everything gets split, joined and expanded twice. Using that cat + heredoc combo, you can avoid all that madness, and pass any command verbatim. You can include a whole script if you like, nicely separated on multiple lines.

Comment: Thanks again @UncleBilly